# Having trouble in sending the results from pdo to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

I want to do is if the user successfully registered the pdo will provide an information and send it to ajax and the ajax will message if the user is registered or not. It was working properly after i put this condition in my pdo and now it wont insert no more and ajax tells "error registering user!" all the time.

script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#submit').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

        var data = {};
        data.name = $('#name').val();
        data.age = $('#age').val();
        data.gender = $('#gender').val();
        data.address = $('#address').val();
        data.image = $('#imgInp').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "user.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
            if (Number(response) == 1)
                {
                alert("User successfully registered");
                }
                      else
                {
                alert("Error registering user!");
                }
            }
        });
            return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

user.php:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$name = @$_POST['name'];
$age = @$_POST['age'];
$address = @$_POST['address'];
$gender = @$_POST['gender'];
$imageName = @$_FILES['image']['name'];


 $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender, imageName ) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender, :image)";

    $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
    $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $query->bindParam(':age', $age);
    $query->bindParam(':address', $address);
    $query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
    $query->bindParam(':image', $imageName);


    $results = $query->execute();
    $results ? echo "1"; : echo "2"; ;
?>
```

Comment: are there any errors? Is the query executing, i.e does it echo 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have error in :

```
$results ? echo "1"; : echo "2"; ;
```

[yours demo](https://eval.in/165118)

try like this  :

```
echo  $results ? "1" : "2";
```

<kbd>[working demo](https://eval.in/165115)</kbd>

you can see [here](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) a tutorial.

Comment: @user3756231 : did you try it ?

Comment: As additional explanation on the error: ternary conditionals do not execute instructions, they return values. Thus using A ? B : C will return B if A evaluates to true, or C if it evaluates to false ; it will not "executes" B or C. Since "echo 1;" is an instruction and not a value, the code results in an error, and the response content that is received by javascript is always different from 1 (whether it is because the response is empty, or a big block of php error text is returned)