# My PDO code always return 0 to ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to do is to check weather the users name already in the database or not and if not it will execute the insert query.

My problem is its always echoing  0 even though the name is not in the database.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "test";

$dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db, $user, $pass);
$dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


$name = @$_POST['name'];
$age = @$_POST['age'];
$address = @$_POST['address'];
$gender = @$_POST['gender'];
$imageName = @$_FILES['image']['name'];


    $dupesql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE name= :name";

    $dupe = $dbc->prepare($dupesql);
    $dupe->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $dupe->execute();     

    if($dupe->rowCount() == 0) 
    {
        echo "0";
        exit;   
    }
    else
    {
         echo "1";

        $q = "INSERT INTO students(name, age, address, gender, imageName ) VALUES(:name, :age, :address, :gender, :image)";

        $query = $dbc->prepare($q);
        $query->bindParam(':name', $name);
        $query->bindParam(':age', $age);
        $query->bindParam(':address', $address);
        $query->bindParam(':gender', $gender);
        $query->bindParam(':image', $imageName);

        $results = $query->execute();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Get rid of the error and warning suppressors in front of $_POST and you might get some insights.

Comment: You accepted an answer for your other question which looks like a carbon copy http://stackoverflow.com/q/24325882/ what is it now? Plus, you mention Ajax; where is it?